# Como implementar um serviços push notification da Apple APNS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notification, apns

Possuo um *web service*, e gostaria de criar um serviço de Push Notification para um app usando APNS da Apple, sem usar o serviço de terceiros, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basicamente tens que implementar esse sistema no teu servidor.
O processo de notificações é feito das seguintes etapas:

- No inicio da aplicação pedes aos "servidores da Apple" para
  registares o dispositivo para aceitar notificações.
- Desse pedido recebes um token referente ao eu dispositivo.
- Envias esse token para o teu servidor, que o irá armazenar.
- Sempre que o teu servidor achar que necessita de enviar notificações
  para os dispositivos, faz um pedido ao servidor da Apple com o token
  do dispositivo.
- O servidor da Apple trata de tentar enviar a notificação para o
  dispositivo.

Existe serviços externos que facilitam e ajudam nesse processo de evitar implementares um servidor para esse processo.
Ve este [exemplo](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) que explica todo o processo e como implementar um servidor.

Comment: Obrigado! Eu vi estes procedimentos com um amigo! Mas sua informação é boa, e trás bom conteúdo para quem está interessado em fazer esta atividade! rs

Comment: Fico contente por ter ajudado.