# Como posso fazer no xCode o código em java mencionado na pergunta?

Tags: objective-c, swift, mobile, xcode

Esta classe em Android quando está ativada, posso fechar o app que ela segue funcionando e mantendo a tela do cell acesa desta forma

Mantem tela acesa:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "watever");
    wl.acquire();
```

//Código completo:

```
public class StreamService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "StreamService";


SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Notification n;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
int notifId = 5315;
PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
IBinder b;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    int x = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
    arg0.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    return b;

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    //FAZ A TELA FICAR LIGADA. . ._
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "watever");
    wl.acquire();
    //__
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = prefs.edit();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.buffering);
    n = new Notification();
    n.icon = R.drawable.icon;
    n.tickerText = "screen ON";
    n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);
    n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
    editor.commit();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.now_playing);
    n.icon = R.drawable.icon;
    n.tickerText = notifMessage;
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    notificationManager.cancel(notifId);
}
}
```

O objetivo é fechar o app e manter a tela ligada, permanecendo nas notificações uma opção pra voltar a abrir o app e negar este processo quando desejado..

Caso alguém possa me auxiliar como posso fazer algo semelhante a uma classe extends servise no xCode e um método semelhante ao de manter a tela acesa, toda dica é válida.

Comment: tente postar o que você já conseguiu fazer ou em que parte do código está com mais dificuldade assim poderemos te ajudar de maneira eficaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado pela atenção, consegui resolver este problema através desses 2 links.

Esse mostra como trabalhar com notificações:
[Como implementar um serviços push notification da Apple APNS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39482/como-implementar-um-servi%C3%A7os-push-notification-da-apple-apns)

Esse mostra como deixa a tela sempre ligada:
[IOS - como fazer a tela do app ficar sempre acesa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110997/ios-como-fazer-a-tela-do-app-ficar-sempre-acesa/111006#111006)

Abraço!