# IOS - como fazer a tela do app ficar sempre acesa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile, xcode

Estou fazendo um app para IOS que já tenho pronto no Android, queria fazer um método que deixasse a tela sempre acesa, mas não estou conseguindo

No Android eu fiz desta forma:

MainActivity:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "watever");
wl.acquire();
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Caso alguém saiba como seria para IOS, fico grato pela ajuda, Abraço!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação da Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled) você pode usar o método `idleTimerDisabled`:

**Swift**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```

Lembrando que você precisa importar o `UIKit`